# TeamCity Nuget Installer is very inconsistent

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package-restore

> TeamCity: 2019.1.1 (build 66192) 
>   Nuget Installer: 5.1.0

As my first build step, I have the nuget installer. I have three (3) package sources listed in my build step. Nuget, DevExpress, and our internal source manifested by teamcity itself.

[image: Package Resources]

When I run the build, it passes every other time.

[image].

When it fails it is because of the TC feed is returning a 401. The full stack trace is as follow:

```
[15:02:22]  [restore]     C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    [15:02:22]  [restore] 
    [15:02:22]  [restore] Feeds used:
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     https://nuget.devexpress.com/ID/api
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json
    [15:02:22]  [restore] Errors in packages.config projects
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     Unable to find version '2019.7.10.4' of package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://nuget.devexpress.com/ID/api: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://nuget.devexpress.com/id/api'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://www.nuget.org/api/v2: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     Unable to find version '2019.7.10.4' of package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.DAL'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://nuget.devexpress.com/ID/api: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.DAL.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://nuget.devexpress.com/id/api'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://www.nuget.org/api/v2: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.DAL.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     Unable to find version '2019.7.10.4' of package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.BLL'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://nuget.devexpress.com/ID/api: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.BLL.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://nuget.devexpress.com/id/api'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://www.nuget.org/api/v2: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.BLL.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     Unable to find version '2019.7.10.4' of package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.MailGun'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://nuget.devexpress.com/ID/api: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.MailGun.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://nuget.devexpress.com/id/api'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://www.nuget.org/api/v2: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.MailGun.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     Unable to find version '2019.7.10.4' of package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.Web'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://teamcity.mydomain.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/ASPNet_Apps/ASP_NET_Apps/v3/index.json.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://nuget.devexpress.com/id/api: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.Web.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://nuget.devexpress.com/id/api'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore]       https://www.nuget.org/api/v2: Package 'AdvancedMetrics.Core.Web.2019.7.10.4' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'.
    [15:02:22]  [restore] 
    [15:02:22]  [restore] Installed:
    [15:02:22]  [restore]     76 package(s) to packages.config projects
    [15:02:22]  [restore] Process exited with code 1
    [15:02:22]  [restore] Process exited with code 1 (Step: NuGet Installer)
    [15:02:22]  [Step 1/5] Step NuGet Installer failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was because I had the variable added to the template. Apparently, you can't do that in TC.

I removed the variable from the template, and added it to the build step manually. It worked!